# With replacements, how many fix-sized samples are needed to cover a normal distribution?

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

Say I have a school of $m$ students in $n$ classrooms, with each classroom having an independent number of students, which follows a normal distribution with $\mu$ as mean and $\sigma$ as std.

Each day, I go to every classroom and **randomly** pick $b$ students **with replacements** from each classroom ($n*b$ students in total per day). $b$ is smaller than or equal to the smallest number of students in a classroom.

How many days do I need to get $k\%$ of all $m$ students picked by me?

IMHO, this question is a bit different from calculating the area of a distribution, since the sampling isn't from the entire $m$ students, but $b$ from each sample(classroom).

Thanks!

Comment: How can the number of students in each classroom be independent, if they must sum to $m$?

Comment: Sorry wrong word used, my point was the number of students in each classroom can be different.

Comment: I feel like $E(ans)$ is simply $k\% * \mu / b$?